# How do i print escape characters as characters?

Tags: c, fgetc, ansi-escape

I'm trying to print escape characters as characters or strings using this code:

```
while((c = fgetc(fp))!= EOF)
{
    if(c == '\0')
    {
        printf("   \0");
    }
    else if(c == '\a')
    {
        printf("   \a");
    }
    else if(c == '\b')
    {
        printf("   \b");
    }
    else if(c == '\f')
    {
        printf("   \f");
    }
    else if(c == '\n')
    {
        printf("   \n");
    }
    else if(c == '\r')
    {
        printf("   \r");
    }
    else if(c == '\t')
    {
        printf("   \t");
    }
    else if(c == '\v')
    {
        printf("   \v");
    }
}
```

but when i try it, it actually prints the escape sequence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Escape the slashes (use `" \\a"`) so they won't get interpreted specially. Also you might want to use a lookup table or a `switch` at least.

```
switch (c) {
case '\0':
    printf("   \\0");
    break;
case '\a':
    printf("   \\a");
    break;
/* And so on. */
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `printf("   \\0");` etc.?

Answer (score 8):

Backslashes in string literals need to be escaped; instead of `"\0"`, you need `"\\0"`.

A lookup table might make this less painful:

```
const char *ecs[256] = {NULL}; // assumes ASCII - may not be a valid assumption
int c;

ecs['\0'] = "\\0";
ecs['\a'] = "\\a";
ecs['\b'] = "\\b";
...
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
  if (ecs[c] == NULL)
    printf("%c", c);
  else
    printf("%s", ecs[c]);
}
```

Yes, the majority of entries in `ecs` are going to be NULL; the tradeoff is that I don't have to worry about mapping the character value to array index.

Comment: What does `ecs` stand for?

Answer (score 3):

For that we need to use double backslash.

Examples:

```
if(c == '\0')
{
    printf("   \\0");
}
else if(c == '\a')
{
    printf("   \\a");
}
else if(c == '\b')
{
    printf("   \\b");
}
else if(c == '\f')
{
    printf("   \\f");
}
else if(c == '\n')
{
    printf("   \\n");
}
else if(c == '\r')
{
    printf("   \\r");
}
else if(c == '\t')
{
    printf("   \\t");
}
else if(c == '\v')
{
    printf("   \\v");
}
```

Should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape `%d` within `printf` to allow you to actually print the characters  "%d":

```
printf("%%d");
```