# Escape character in C

Tags: c

So I want to  check if someone enters: `\n` (`'\'` and then `'n'`) from the keyboard to a string, so I'm doing something like this:

```
if ( ((str[i] == '\') && (str[i+1] == 'n')) ) {
    //...
}
```

However this doesn't work because it recognizes `\` as an escape character and the whole thing breaks.

Any better way to do this ?

Comment: Public service announcement: We don't need 20 (similar) answers on a simple question like this.

Comment: @HamZa: especially when (.. counting) exactly *half* seem to focus on precisely the wrong thing.

Comment: @Xaloni if this doesn't work, you may comment the answer that gave you this and maybe edit your question to explain *why* it doesn't work (what does it do and why this is not what you want).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i print escape characters as characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684976/how-do-i-print-escape-characters-as-characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape `\` by doubling it:

```
if ( ((str[i] == '\\') && (str[i+1] == 'n')) ){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The escape sequence for an actual backslash is `\\`, e.g.

```
char c = getchar();
if(c == '\\')
    ... stuff ...
```

Answer (score 1):

compare the \ like this.
`if ((str[i] == '\\') && (str[i+1] == 'n'))`

because we have to escape the escape sequence \.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of escape characters you can use the ASCII values like this

```
  if ((str[i] == 92) && (str[i+1] == 'n'))
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you use another \

```
    if ( str[i] == '\\' && str[i+1] == 'n');
```

Comment: This *answer* would be SO MUCH better if you added a sentence explaining escape cnd reserved characters.

Comment: That would be the second one trying to explain rather than just saying "You have to.", Himanshu's answer added a quick explanation but got downvoted for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

if user enter like `\` and `n` using keyboard .

then try like this

```
 if(str[i] == '\\' && str[i+1] == 'n')
```

As `\` is represented by `\\`, so use `\\` instead of `\` to check.